# 'of' or 'for' in this sentence

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

> A lonely day is God's way *of* saying that he wants to spend some quality time with you.
>
> A lonely day is God's way *for* saying that he wants to spend some quality time with you.

Which is better and why? Thanks!

Comment: The expression is *a way of saying* something. You could use *for* in a different context, such as: *For saying this, you will pay a price*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/way) suggests that when **way** is used to mean an action that can produce the result you want, there are two possibilities: you can use **of** + a gerund (-ing) or use **to** + an infinitive. Here are two examples:

> There are many ways **of solving** the problem.
>   That's not the way **to do** it - let me show you.

This is backed up by [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=way%20of%20saying%2C%20way%20to%20say%2C%20way%20for%20saying&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cway%20of%20saying%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cway%20to%20say%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cway%20for%20saying%3B%2Cc0), which shows that **way of saying** and **way to say** are both considerably more common than **way for saying**. If you look at the actual instances of **way for saying**, you will find that the general standard of literacy in these documents is not very high, for example:

> It's just another way for saying truly take care of yourself, truly. Don't say it and do it for no one else but for you. Might be good to seek Reiki or Healing just to help open you up to your solitude. *[My light - Alex Craig (2015)](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=snsbBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA18&dq=%22way%20for%20saying%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22way%20for%20saying%22&f=false)*